# porting program created in visual studio using windows 10 uwp to android or ios

Tags: c#, android, ios, uwp

I was wondering if there is a program out there that can convert a simple app I made in Visual studio using UWP to android or iOS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say that's impossible, currently there is not such tool or program to convert UWP to IOS or Android app directly, For developing cross-platform app within .NET, you could refer to Xamarin Forms. [`Xamarin.Forms`](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/xamarin/xamarin-forms) is an open source cross-platform framework from Microsoft for building iOS, Android, & Windows apps with .NET from a single shared codebase.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I didnt see any tools or programs that could but I thought I would ask!!